# Runtime Error in Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-error-reporting, visual-c++, runtime-error

I am currently getting the following error whenever I boot to Windows:

[image: Runtime Error]

Which began after I uninstalled ibVPN.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of it? Perhaps something in the registry, but I'm wondering which key, and in which section of the registry...

Comment: You need to determine which version of the Visual C++ runtime is required for this program and reinstall it.  You might also contact the author of the program for support, I don't have high hopes, that fixing the installation will solve this particular problem.  *The error is normally caused by just bad programming.*

Comment: The error occurred after I uninstalled the program via the Windows Add/Remove Programs option in the Control Panel.

Comment: I don't understand.  You made no mention of uninstalling a program in your question.  Which program did you uninstall precisely?  [Just modify your registry so this program isn't started when you log into your profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

Comment: @Ramound: ibVPN